# quarkus native reflection configuration for whole package

Tags: kotlin, reflection, native, quarkus

I'm building quarkus native and using Stripe sdk as external library.
In order to support Stripe sdk it I needed to create **reflection-config.json** file and set in the application.properties **quarkus.native.additional-build-args=-H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=reflection-config.json**

The **reflection-config.json** looks like so:

```
  {
    "name": "com.stripe.model.Customer",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "allPublicConstructors": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredFields": true,
    "allPublicFields": true
  },
  {
    "name": "com.stripe.model.Customer$InvoiceSettings",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "allPublicConstructors": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredFields": true,
    "allPublicFields": true
  },
  {
    "name": "com.stripe.model.StripeError",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "allPublicConstructors": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredFields": true,
    "allPublicFields": true
  },
  {
    "name": "com.stripe.model.PaymentIntent",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "allPublicConstructors": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredFields": true,
    "allPublicFields": true
  },
  {
    "name": "com.stripe.model.PaymentMethod",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "allPublicConstructors": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredFields": true,
    "allPublicFields": true
  }....
```

and so on.
It contains too many classes.
My question is if there is a way to set the whole package instead of tons of classes?
For example:

```
  {
    "name": "com.stripe.model.*",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "allPublicConstructors": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredFields": true,
    "allPublicFields": true
  }
```

Didn't find any mention for it.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with a Quarkus extension, get classes from the index and produce a `ReflectiveClassBuildItem` for all classes matching the package.

It's not that hard but requires a bit of work.

A less verbose alternative to what you're doing is to use `@RegisterForReflection(targets = { ... })`.

That's the only alternatives right now.

Comment: Is this still true in 2023?  Can this function be used in Quarkus to loop over a whole package adding classes: https://www.graalvm.org/22.3/reference-manual/native-image/dynamic-features/Reflection/#configuration-with-features

Answer (score 2):

**See update below.**

I'm having the exact same use case to programmatically add all classes of a package for reflection without writing an extension.
My goal is to add jOOQ generated DB classes for reflection so I can use them in a native compiled Quarkus GraalVM image with RESTEasy Reactive Jackson.
As there are a lot of these classes I don't really want to manually populate the `reflection-config.json` or the targets with a `@RegisterForReflection` annotation on a empty class.

I'm using Quarkus [2.7.0.Final (not `io.quarkus.platform` as it is not released yet)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-bom/2.7.0.Final) with Gradle 7.3.3 and **tried the following, which unfortunately does not work**.
But I guess this only works when building extensions

```java
package com.example.restapi.graal;

import io.quarkus.deployment.annotations.BuildProducer;
import io.quarkus.deployment.annotations.BuildStep;
import io.quarkus.deployment.builditem.CombinedIndexBuildItem;
import io.quarkus.deployment.builditem.nativeimage.ReflectiveClassBuildItem;
import org.jboss.jandex.ClassInfo;
import org.jboss.jandex.IndexView;

public class JooqReflectionProcessor {

    private static final String JOOQ_DB_REFLECT_CLASSES = "com\\.example\\.restapi\\.db\\..+\\.tables\\.(pojos|records)\\..+";

    @BuildStep
    public void build(BuildProducer<ReflectiveClassBuildItem> reflectiveClass, CombinedIndexBuildItem indexBuildItem) {
        IndexView index = indexBuildItem.getIndex();
        for (ClassInfo clazz : index.getKnownClasses()) {
            if (clazz.name().toString().matches(JOOQ_DB_REFLECT_CLASSES)) {
                reflectiveClass.produce(new ReflectiveClassBuildItem(true, true, clazz.name().toString()));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Update:**

It ain't pretty but I ended up writing a Gradle task which automatically creates the desired jOOQ reflection class with the `@RegisterForReflection(targets = {...})` annotation:

```java
task writeJooqReflectionClass {
    DefaultSourceDirectorySet sourceSet = project.sourceSets.findByName('main').java

    File jooqSrcDir = sourceSet.srcDirs
        .stream()
        .filter { it.path.replace('\\', '/').matches('.+src/generated/jooq/main') }
        .findFirst()
        .get()

    ArrayList<String> classesForReflection = sourceSet
        .filter {
            it.path.contains(jooqSrcDir.path) &&
                it.path.replace('\\', '/').matches('.+tables/(pojos|records)/.+') &&
                it.path.endsWith('.java')
        }
        .collect { it.path.replaceAll('[\\\\|/]', '.').substring(jooqSrcDir.path.length() + 1).replace('.java', '.class') }

    Collections.sort(classesForReflection)

    File file = new File("${jooqSrcDir.path}/com/example/restapi/db", "JooqReflectionConfig.java")
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs()
    file.text = """\
    package com.example.restapi.db;

    import io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.RegisterForReflection;

    @RegisterForReflection(targets = {
        ${String.join(',\n        ', classesForReflection)}
    })
    public class JooqReflectionConfig {

    }
    """.stripIndent()
}

compileJava.dependsOn(writeJooqReflectionClass)
```

For example produces Class `com.example.restapi.db.JooqReflectionConfig` with content:

```java
package com.example.restapi.db;

import io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.RegisterForReflection;

@RegisterForReflection(targets = {
    com.example.restapi.db.master.tables.pojos.TableA.class,
    com.example.restapi.db.master.tables.pojos.TableB.class,
    com.example.restapi.db.master.tables.records.TableA.class,
    com.example.restapi.db.master.tables.records.TableB.class,
    com.example.restapi.db.mdc.tables.pojos.TableC.class,
    com.example.restapi.db.mdc.tables.pojos.TableD.class,
    com.example.restapi.db.mdc.tables.records.TableC.class,
    com.example.restapi.db.mdc.tables.records.TableD.class
})
public class JooqReflectionConfig {

}
```

Comment: I wonder if it wouldn't be simpler to annotate each of the generated classes individually. We use Maven instead of Gradle. `io.github.floverfelt:find-and-replace-maven-plugin` is configured to replace `^public class ` with `@io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.RegisterForReflection 
public class ` in those generated classes.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest solution seems to be writing a Quarkus extension.

Or, if you don't want to list `RegisterForReflection` targets manually, another possibility is to have `reflection-config.json` generated externally (probably using annotation processor? or maven/gradle task).