# Running Quarkus in native Mode fails: Image Generation failed. Does Quarkus native Mode support Jooq Generation

Tags: maven, native, quarkus, jooq, jooq-codegen-maven

Running `./mvnw package -Dnative` followed by this error:

```
[ERROR]     [error]: Build step io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep#build threw an exception: io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep$ImageGenerationFailureException: Image generation failed. Exit code: 1
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.imageGenerationFailed(NativeImageBuildStep.java:397)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.build(NativeImageBuildStep.java:238)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:882)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
```

I've already ran another Quarkus project successfully in native mode without Jooq generation. I am very sure the problem is caused by Jooq. We are using the Jooq plugin in our pom.xml in such way:

```
<plugin>
               <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
               <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
               <version>3.16.4</version>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <id>jooq-codegen-exec1</id>
                       <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>generate</goal>
                       </goals>
                       <configuration>
                           <jdbc>
                               <driver>org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                               <url>jdbc:mariadb://127.0.0.1:3306</url>
                               <user>admin</user>
                               <password>admin</password>
                           </jdbc>
                           <generator>
                               <database>
                                   <includes>.*</includes>
                                   <inputSchema>hvb3</inputSchema>
                               </database>
                               <target>
                                   <packageName>hvbJooq</packageName>
                                   <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                               </target>
                           </generator>
                       </configuration>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
               <dependencies>
                   <dependency>
                       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                       <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                       <version>8.0.27</version>
                   </dependency>
                   <dependency>
                       <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
                       <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
                       <version>3.0.3</version>
                   </dependency>
               </dependencies>
           </plugin>
```

Does anybody know anything about this issue?

Comment: Are you using this third party integration contribution? https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-jooq

Comment: @LukasEder hello, yes, this one

Answer (score 0):

I'm using jOOQ Pro Java 17 with Quarkus & GraalVM native mode for more than half a year in production, but personally I'm not using the Quarkiverse jOOQ extension as it is outdated and is rather difficult to work with jOOQ Express/Pro/Enterprise.
I'd like to keeps things up-to-date, my latest prod build is running with Quarkus 2.9.2.Final, jOOQ Pro 3.16.6 Java 17 and GraalVM 22.1.0 Java 17.

For building the microservices last year I switched from Maven to Gradle and luckily I did so, so I could write the following Gradle task that automatically registers all jOOQ generated POJOs, Records and Routines for GraalVM reflection before the GraalVM build is started.

[quarkus native reflection configuration for whole package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65798326/quarkus-native-reflection-configuration-for-whole-package/70870930#70870930)

I hope this helps.